# How can I prevent Word 2010 moving page breaks when hidden text is displayed?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have to work with a set of document templates that provide instructions in hidden text. If I enable the display of hidden text, then the page breaks shown on-screen don't match the way the document prints.

Is there a way to enable the display of hidden text, but also show the location of the page breaks as they will print? The best solution I've come up with is to use the show/hide button (Ctrl-*), but I don't need to see all of the formatting marks.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add the hidden instructions in textboxes in front of the document content instead of directly in the document body. This way, when the hidden text is shown the document structure will not change as the text is separate from the main text.

Textboxes and shapes can also be made hidden in the same way as regular text (highlight the textbox and choose Font -> Hidden).